# A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here! A/brutx.mymodeap: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-glide

In the test activity, I try to download images using Glide and combine them into one bitmap, which I then insert into ImageView, an error occurs at the moment when I exit this Activity by clicking <- or even going to another activity, the error occurs because something is still being done with the bitmap inside Glide, and when the activity dies, the bitmaps die along with it, but the functions still work. I tried using coroutines, but it didn't help... Help

```
A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
A/brutx.mymodeap: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
    runtime.cc:655] All threads:
    runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (34):
    runtime.cc:655] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x71472008 self=0xe6cc0010
    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=3564 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xf5128478
    runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 1709725586 1316493703 1314 ) utm=51 stm=119 core=1 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xff593000-0xff595000 stackSize=8192KB
    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00542d7e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+110)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 006a0877  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+1015)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0069a151  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+65)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 006c6194  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1172)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006bf246  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+630)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 006be1ae  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+2446)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 0065225d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+445)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 0063982f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1967)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #09 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threaded Bitmap operation, if Bitmap is recycled in other threads, create a bitmap in this thread will cause a native crash.

Comment: How do I stop this usage?